# twilio voice call not connecting

Tags: javascript, ruby, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I'm trying to make a browser to phone number call using twilio voip.

Currently I'm generating a token for the Javascript client like so

```
account_sid = 'xxx'
auth_token = 'xxx'
capability = Twilio::Util::Capability.new account_sid, auth_token
capability.allow_client_incoming self.email
capability.allow_client_outgoing 'xxx'
capability.generate
```

I have checked that my account_sid and auth_token are the live account.

'allow_client_outgoing' is set to the twiml application sid.

I have also set the twiml voice request url to my webservice end point, which returns the appropriate xml when tested using curl.

When the browser attempts to make a call, the call is immediately hung up, and my webservice is never hit.

I have also checked twilio for any alerts, but nothing is there.

What could the problem be? I assume it's something to do with the token I am generating, but the code is so simple I can see what could be wrong.

Comment: Hi! Megan from Twilio. Try `token = capability.generate` - does that do it? Otherwise what do you see if you console log or check the Twilio App Monitor?

Comment: `capability.generate` does exactly the same as `token = capability.generate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several things, I thought that this line might be the issue
`capability.allow_client_incoming self.email`

Seems that you can't have special characters in the 'allow_client_incoming' string.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to set the token to `token.generate`,

```
capability = Twilio::Util::Capability.new account_sid, auth_token
capability.allow_client_incoming self.email
capability.allow_client_outgoing 'xxx'
capability_token = capability.generate
```

In my controller I'm rendering `json: {token: capability_token}`

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing at the moment (with different variable names).